# Is it necessary to split mapState between a string array and object spread operator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am working with Vuex and I have 2 states:

```
state: {
  token: 'xyz',
  user: {
     id: 1,
     user: 'cody',
     username: 'cody'
     }
}
```

In the component, I have used the following:

```
<template>
<div>
  <button @click="getProfile">
      click to get profile
  </button>
  <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: "Profile",
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            token: "token",
        }),
        ...mapState(["user"])
    },
    methods: {
        getProfile() {
            fetch("http://localhost:3000/profile", {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`,
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Noticed at the computed section I have used 2 mapState rather than one.

```
computed: {
        ...mapState({
            token: "token",
        }),
        ...mapState(["user"])
    },
```

May I ask if it is possible to declare the string array **and** object spread operator together in a single mapState declaration? Because right now I need to have 2 mapState in order to make it work. So I am just wondering if I am missing anything when I only use one mapState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no other computed properties and you're not renaming the `token` state, you can simply use

```js
computed: mapState(["token", "user"]),
```

The `mapState` helper only accepts one argument, either a string array or an object so no, you cannot mix the array and object formats. Based on your comment below, you could do something like this...

```js
computed: mapState({
  token: "token",
  user: "user"
})
```

though I really don't see why you would

Comment: Thanks @Phil. I am more curious to know whether I could write it like this: ```...mapState({token: "token"}, ["user"])```?

Comment: @Beaumont I've update my answer. You should also try reading the documentation which states the allowed parameters ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper

Comment: Thank you. I read the doc but it wasn't quite clear whether I could do that in my first comment. Your amended answer helped a tonne, thanks!